# How to prevent a multi-file upload timing out in Coldfusion?

Tags: file-upload, coldfusion, timeout

I have an automatic routine, that can be triggered by users to upload images to Amazon S3. Users usually will have >500 items to upload and I'm struggeling to find a way to not have the process time out.

Right now I'm doing this:

```
<form action="hs_import.cfm?ansicht=Bilder&RequestTimeout=5000" method="post" name="uploader">
...
    <input type="button" OnClick="bilder_upload()" value="#tx_gen_run#">
    <input type="hidden" name="artikel_uploaden" value="ja">
    <input type="hidden" name="ansicht" value="imageloader">
</form>
```

Which triggers a javascript function, which triggers my upload (sans details):

```
<cfif isdefined("artikel_uploaden")>
<cfscript>
        S3 variables
</cfscript>

    <!--- get img paths to upload --->
    <cfquery datasource="db" name="img_paths">
    SELECT DISTINCT imgpath
</cfquery>

    <cfif img_paths.recordcount GT 0>
        <cfloop query="img_paths">
            <cfif img_paths.typ NEQ "img">
                <cfset variables.testFilePath = img_paths.bildpfad & img_paths.bilddateiname>
                <cfset variables.fileExt = ListLast(variables.testFilePath, ".")>


                <!--- get image --->
                <cfhttp timeout="45" 
                    throwonerror="no" 
                    url="#variables.testFilePath#" 
                    method="get" 
                    useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.8.1.12) Gecko/20080201 Firefox/2.0.0.12" 
                    getasbinary="yes" 
                    result="variables.objGet">

                <!--- validate --->
                <!--- upload 4 sizes (s,m,l,xl) to S3 --->          
                <cftry>
                    <cfset objImage = ImageNew(variables.objGet.FileContent )>
                    <cfimage source="#objImage#" action="write" quality=".99" destination="#variables.tempDirectory#_base_#img_paths.bilddateiname#" overwrite="yes">
                    <cfset variables.basePath = variables.tempDirectory & "_base_" & img_paths.bilddateiname>
                    <cfimage action="read" source="#variables.basePath#" name="base">
                    <cfset variables.imageSrc = variables.tempDirectory>
                    <cfscript>
                        if ( ImageGetWidth( base ) LT ImageGetHeight( base ) ) {
                        // portrait                                     
                        } else {
                        // landscape/square

                        }
                        // cleanup
                    </cfscript>

                    <!--- create IMG entry in media table  --->
                    <cfquery datasource="db"></cfquery>
                </cfif>
            <cfcatch>
                <cfset variables.errorCount = variables.errorCount+1>
                <cfset variables.failedLoads = variables.failedLoads & img_paths.bilddateiname & "  (" & tx_pop_error & ":" & tx_errors_import_ext & "), ">
            </cfcatch>
        </cftry>
    </cfif>
  </cfloop>
  <!--- alert on success and errors --->
</cfif>
```

This works ok, but the browser just hangs up/times out if the number of images is too large, so I'm usually looking at a loading screen which never finished and does not alert success/error.

**Question**:
What would be a better alternative to handling a large file upload like this? Should this go into a `cfschedule`, for example, so it can run in the background?

Thanks for hints!

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to do an awful lot in a single request. While one or five images may not generate timeouts, hundreds of messages certainly will. From the code you provided above, you're doing the following in a single request:

1. Upload [n] images
2. Make an http request to fetch each image
3. Resize each image (possibly into 4 different sizes, not entirely clear from the sample)
4. Upload each manipulated version of each image to S3

That's a lot of work, especially given that both cfhttp and, more specifically, cfimage are not the fastest tags in the language. Image manipulation via cfimage can be quite slow.

You're probably much better off doing what you suggested: breaking these tasks apart and doing as much of the processing on the backend so that the original customer request doesn't have to wait. You could do the initial image upload and then end the customer request, notifying them that it may take a few minutes for all of their images to be processed.

You then have the option of using a scheduled task or a task queue (ie; Rabbit MQ) to do the image processing and uploading to S3. I'd even suggest that you have a separate instance which handles scheduled tasks, so that this processing work isn't done on the instances where customers are interacting directly with your web app. Breaking the image manipulation and S3 upload into separate tasks might even be better, so that you can have error handling to capture problems with image manipulation (ie; bad file formats) without also borking the S3 upload process. This requires a bit more tracking work on the backend (ie; which images still need processing, which images still need uploading to S3) but this isn't hard to implement and gives you a more robust workflow setup overall.

Comment: also, thanks. Yes I'm creating 4 sizes from the uploaded image. I'm still not sure what the best way to upload the images is. My process is working, but takes forever (sidenote: I have given up telling users, that 5MB images are no good to upload or use and am happy the images are in the right folder ;-) Still I guess I will eventually move the process into a `cfschedule` and run it sometime later. Is Rabbit MQ good for that? One thing I'm not sure about is breaking this up into separate tasks. If I'm scheduling, I might as well run the whole batch.

Comment: Rabbit MQ is a task queue. It's very useful for putting tasks in a queue, tracking status, and removing them from the queue when they're done. If you were to create a truly decomposed set of services (that is, breaking the image validation, resizing, uploading into S3, and notification to the customer into separate services), Rabbit MQ would probably help a lot. You're right though: you could do this as a single scheduled task. The nice thing about breaking things apart is that it's easy to swap code when needed and its easier to handle errors.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping over a cfquery, which is very bad to do, and can cause major slowdowns.  One way around this is to store a 100 queries into a variable and then run multiple queries at once (its the open and closing of the connection that can take a long time.)  When I used to use this style for mass updates,  would get an improved performance of 90% faster.

This may be enough to get your process working.  Of course, if you have a lot of really large images, there is not much to do about that (except limit image size)

Comment: hm. I like the idea. Can you tell me how to store "a 100 query in a variable"? never did that before. Thx so far.

Comment: @frequent:  I'm doing this from memory (don't code in CF anymore) but just create a variable, and store the queries in it seperated by a semi colon.  Then just every 100 loops, dump the value of the variable into a cfquery.  As I remember, you will need to use PreserveSingleQuotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted the users to trigger the request you could do it with an AJAX call and just not wait for a reply. Simply tell the user that the request is running in the background.  You could also use cfthread to start the large request while completing the page thread and displaying a 'Request in process' page.

[Ask Ben: Processing Files With CFThread In ColdFusion](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1886-Ask-Ben-Processing-Files-With-CFThread-In-ColdFusion.htm)